# Installing cuDNN for Deep Learning on a Server: Local or Global Installation?

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I have access to a server and wish to execute Python scripts for Deep Learning with GPU acceleration.
However, even though CUDA is installed, I am encountering an issue where I cannot locate the necessary cuDNN files.

If I want to install cuDNN files (https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) should I install them locally in my home directory or globally on the server?